# "gdb.exe has stopped working " in windows7

Tags: windows-7, build, gdb

I build `GDB for ARM` from GDDBSources(`GDB7.5`) using `MinGW` and `MSYS` for windows.But sometimes while connecting `GDB` to the `QEMU` , GDB crash occurs with a message :

`"gdb.exe has stopped working"` in windows7.

What is the solution of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation before. The solution is using mingw-w64 in place of MinGW in windows 7. It works well for me.